# formula in criteria range in SUMIFS

Tags: excel, sumifs

Can I apply formula in criteria range in SUMIFS as I don't want to do it outside.

I am trying something like below-

```
=SUMIFS('sheet1'!D:D,(LEFT('sheet2'!A:A,6)),"="&LEFT('sheet3'!B1,6))
```

Comment: Why? Show an example of data and expected result.

Comment: Is that a typo, or is it really the case that the `SUMIFS` *sum_range* is in Sheet1 but the *criteria_range* is in Sheet2?

Comment: @JosWoolley jus typo.. My ask is to use the LEFT formula in criteria range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that kind of manipulation doesn't work in SumIfs. You would need to use SumProduct. You shouldn't use full column references with that, since that will be very slow.

```
=SUMProduct('sheet1'!$D$1:$D$1000,--(LEFT('sheet2'!$A$1:$A$1000,6)=LEFT('sheet3'!B1,6)))
```

Answer (score 0):

For `SUMIFS`, you would need a different set-up using wildcards:

`=SUMIFS(Sheet1!D:D,Sheet1!A:A,LEFT(Sheet3!B1,6)&"*")`

though note that this will not work if the entries in `Sheet1!A:A` are numeric.

Comment: @teylyn It references the entire cell contents in each of the entries in column A, that is true. However, it is only comparing the first 6 characters nevertheless, thanks to the wildcard used in the *criteria*.

Comment: I think we're going round in circles here, since I believe that's precisely what my formula is doing. Perhaps it would be more constructive if you came up with a single example for which my formula fails?